# How to add comma to numbers in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to get MySQL to return a value with a comma? I have this MySQL query which returns values with 5 digits, for example 14123, but I want it to be 14.123. I read something about the `FORMAT()` function but I'm not really sure how to use it together with my query, and I want to avoid using PHP.

My query looks like this:

```
public function artists_count_get()  
    { 
        $this->load->database();
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT artist_id ) AS artists FROM artists";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        $data = $query->result();

        if($data) {
            $this->response($data, 200); 
        } else {
            $this->response(array('error' => 'There was an error'), 404);
        }
    }
```

Comment: what you actually are unsure about FORMAT?

Comment: Also, as suggested in the question I marked this a duplicate of, you should ask yourself why you are avoiding doing the formatting in the presentation layer (PHP).

Comment: @Dan I use BackboneJS as frontend and Restful API, so I have no use for PHP, sorry for not mentioning...

Comment: @RoyalBg why do you think I ask?

Comment: I've tidied up the question a bit. You may wish to improve it further, as the title requests a comma and the body requests either a comma or a dot separator, depending on which bit you read.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT FORMAT(COUNT( DISTINCT artist_id ),0) AS artists FROM artists";
```

More info about using FORMAT: [MySQL FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

Comment: is it maybe possible to change the comma to a dot?

Comment: In MySQL v5.6 FORMAT, you can specify a locale: [MySQL FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

Answer (score 4):

[FORMAT(X,D)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) Formats the number X to a format like '###,###.##', rounded to D decimal places, and returns the result as a string. If D is 0, the result has no decimal point or fractional part. Try

```
$sql = "SELECT FORMAT(COUNT( DISTINCT artist_id ), 0) AS artists FROM artists";
```